# Retrieving UITextField data in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tags, uitextfield

I want to retrive the entered data in my UITextField and assign it to a parameter. I'm trying to assign tags to the textfields but the tags all become 0.

The code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * defaultCellId = @"DefaultCell";
    static NSString * fieldCellId = @"FieldCell";
    static NSString * pictureCellId = @"PictureCell";

    DefaultCell *defaultCell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:defaultCellId];
    FieldCell *fieldCell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:fieldCellId];
    PictureCell *pictureCell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:pictureCellId];

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        if (fieldCell == nil) {
            fieldCell = [[FieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:fieldCellId];
        }

        fieldCell.field.tag = indexPath.row + 1; //**THIS LINE**

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            fieldCell.label.text = @"Namn";
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            fieldCell.label.text = @"E-post";
        if (indexPath.row == 2)
            fieldCell.label.text = @"Telefon";
        return fieldCell;

    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        if (defaultCell == nil) {
            defaultCell = [[DefaultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:defaultCellId];
        }
        defaultCell.label.text = @"Plats";
        return defaultCell;

    } else if(indexPath.section == 3) {

        if (fieldCell == nil) {
            fieldCell = [[FieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:fieldCellId];
        }
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
            fieldCell.label.text = @"Titel";
        if(indexPath.row == 1)
            fieldCell.label.text = @"Text";
        return fieldCell;

    } else if(indexPath.section == 4) {

        if (pictureCell == nil) {
            pictureCell = [[PictureCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:pictureCellId];
        }
        pictureCell.label.text = @"Bild";
        return pictureCell;

    } else {

        if (defaultCell == nil) {
            defaultCell = [[DefaultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:defaultCellId];
        }
        defaultCell.label.text = @"Lägg upp annons";
        return defaultCell;
    }
}
```

It´s something like this in the textFieldDidEndEditing method I want.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if(textField.tag == 1)
        NSString *title = textField.text;
    if(textField.tag == 2)
        NSString *phone == textField.text;
}
```

Appreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using three different custom cells use a single cell with all the three components in it.
and assign a tag number while creating your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
CueTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CueTableCell XibName" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    // Set tag to textField here and implement Delegate method of it to read value
    [cell.textField setTag:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For table views with several UITextFields, I definitely recommend the free Sensible TableView framework. In your case, the framework will automatically create the fields from your object's properties, then it will also automatically set their values from whatever the user enters there. I find it really handy.